# Bitstream parsing and Endianness

Tags: c++, bit-shift, endianness, bitstream

I am trying to parse a bitstream, and I am having trouble getting my head around endianness. I have a byte buffer, and I need to be able to read bitfields out which are of varying lengths, anywhere from 1 bit to 8 bits mostly.

My problem comes with the endianness of the bytes. When I step through with a debugger, the bottom 4 bits appear to be in the top portion of the byte. That is, where I am expecting the first two bits to be 10 (they *must* be 10), however, the first byte in the bitstream is 0xA3, or 1010 0011, when checking with the debugger. Meaning, assuming that the bits are in the "correct" order, the first two bits are in fact 11 (reading right to left).

It would seem, however, that if the bits were not in the right order, and should be 0x3A, or 0011 1010, I then have 10 as my expected first two bits.

This confuses me, because it doesn't seem to be a matter of bit order, MSb to LSb/LSb to MSb, but rather nibble order. How does this happen? That seems to just be the way it came out of the file. There is a possibility this is an invalid bitstream, but I have seen this kind of thing before when reading files in Hex Editors, nibbles seemingly in the "wrong" order.

I am just confused and would like some help understanding what's going on. I don't often deal with things at this level.

Comment: To my understanding first two bytes of `0xA3` (ie `10100011`) **are** `10`, followed by `100011`. I've never found nibble inversion, endianness usualy referes to **byte** order. Here I think the **bit order** is the opposite of what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to concern the bit order, because in C/C++ there is no way for you to iterate through the bits using pointer arithmetics. You can only manipulate the bits using bit-wise operators that are independent of the bit order of the local machine. What you mentioned in the OP is just a matter of visualization. Different debuggers may choose different ways to visualize the bits in a byte. There is no right or wrong for this matter. There is just preference. What really matters if the byte order.

Comment: I think I might be doing it right but something else is going wrong.